# Identify subsets of root data in a list of trees

Tags: c#, linq, task-parallel-library, intersection

I have following structure:

```
Node
{
    List<String> rootData;
    List<Node> Children;
}
```

and a collection as

```
List<Node> lstOfTrees
```

the first Structure holds some words on rootData, (List of node is not really important here) and the collection **lstOfTrees** contains the the trees.

Problem is:
In **lstOfTrees**, there are multiple trees. Some of the trees have subset of rootData of other trees (possibly, not necessarily). I want to keep the tree having super-set of other rootData(s) in lstOfTrees (subset should be ignored).

example:
assuming, lstOfTrees contain the trees as

```
1: {rootData: A, B, C, D}
2: {rootData: E, F, G}
3: {rootData: G, H}
4: {rootData: J, A, C}
5: {rootData: D, Z}
```

the final answer I need, should be in a new list containing:

```
1: {rootData: A, B, C, D}
2: {rootData: E, F, G}
```

Can this be done using LINQ and TPL (or the more effecient way) ? I want it to be efficient and correct.

**EDIT:**

should the following code work correctly in all cases or am I missing something??

```
lstOfTrees.Add(new node());
lstOfTrees[0].rootData = new List<string> {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
lstOfTrees.Add(new node());
lstOfTrees[1].rootData = new List<string> {"E", "F", "G"};
lstOfTrees.Add(new node());
lstOfTrees[2].rootData = new List<string> {"G", "H"};
lstOfTrees.Add(new node());
lstOfTrees[3].rootData = new List<string> {"J", "A", "C"};
lstOfTrees.Add(new node());
lstOfTrees[4].rootData = new List<string> {"D", "Z"};


Dictionary<int,node> dictOfTrees_indexToNode = Enumerable.Range(0, lstOfTrees.Count).ToDictionary(x=>x,x => lstOfTrees[x]);

List<int> notToInclude = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < lstOfTrees.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < lstOfTrees.Count; j++)
    {
        if (j != i)
        {
            if (!lstOfTrees[j].Equals(lstOfTrees[i]))
            {
                if (lstOfTrees[j].rootData.Join(lstOfTrees[i].rootData, root => root, innerRoot => innerRoot,
                                                (root, innerRoot) => 1).Any())
                {
                    bool test = (lstOfTrees[j].rootData.Count > lstOfTrees[i].rootData.Count);
                    notToInclude.Add(test ? i : j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

List<node> finalList = new List<node>();
finalList.AddRange(lstOfTrees.Except(notToInclude.Select(s=>dictOfTrees_indexToNode[s])));
```

**Also, Can I improve from this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified the case a little bit for testing to just searching through the list of list of strings, which should be the same thing that you're doing after a small middle step:

```
var list = lstOfTrees.Select(x => new HashSet<string>(x.rootData)).ToList();
```

Also, it's quite possible that it would be better to use sets here, at least *I don't see any duplicates in the example data*, and that's the second change.

Using sets here is quite important, so if data can - in fact - be duplicated in the lists, then the whole solution would have to change.

Here's the result:

```
var list = new List<List<string>> {
        new List<string> {"A", "B", "C", "D"},
        new List<string> {"E", "F", "G"},
        new List<string> {"G", "H"},
        new List<string> {"J", "A", "C"},
        new List<string> {"D", "Z"}};

var sets = list.Select(x => new HashSet<string>(x)).ToList();

var result = sets.Select(x => sets.Where(y => x.Overlaps(y)) // You are looking not for 'subsets', but overlapping sets
                                  .OrderByDescending(y => y.Count)
                                  .FirstOrDefault())
                 .Distinct();
```

This returns `IEnumerable<HashSet<string>>`:

> {"A", "B", "C", "D"}, {"E", "F", "G"}

Tested in LINQPad :)

Comment: 1> you're right, strings are unique within one node.
2> will let you know after testing on my application :) Thanks. (and linqPad is new thing for me)